# swift is slow at updating view after a REST POST request

Tags: rest, swift, drawrect

I'm sending some POST request to my sever with swift, the usual:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println(responseString) //this is fast
        label.text = "\(responseString)" // this is very slow
}
task.resume()
```

This works well, I get the data and all. Now there are 2 things that behave very differently and I can't figure out why.

The line: `println(responseString)` print the data instantly as expected, however, the line `label.text = "\(responseString)"` takes about 10 seconds to update the label's text.

Any ideas why? has DrawRect got anything to do with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing it on the main thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        label.text = "\(responseString)"
    })
```

Comment: No problem! Whenever you do computations, network requests etc on a background thread then update the UI, always do it on the main thread like this.